# with(data, expr) construct inside a function renders its parameters invisible?

Tags: r

I'm trying to pass an environment into a function, but can't seem to use it using the ``with'' construct.
In the code below:

```
f <- function(i,env)with(env, i+2*j)

g <- function() {
  env <- new.env()
  env$j <- 3
  f(10, env)
}

g()
```

I would have expected that inside the ``with'', i would be visible, so g() should return 16. However, I get

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i' not found
```

I notice that the docu says that

> if ‘data’ is already an environment then this is used with its
>   existing parent,

but that would seem to completely short-circuit all arguments of a function.
Wny is this, and why would this be useful behaviour?

(The background to this is that I'm cleaning up old code that had some biggish global variables; 
I'm trying to stuff that into a big environment that gets passed around, and my hope was that
I didn't need to rewrite all read/writes from/to those previously global variables).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: (just out of interest, why do people vote this question down? Is this out of spite or so? It hardly seems newbie stuff and answers to it would be useful to anyone, I imagine)

Answer (score 2):

`i` is in the environment of `f`, but it isn't in the environment of `env`.  You would have to  do

```
f <- function(i,env) with(env,j)*2+i

g <- function() {
  env <- new.env()
  env$j <- 3
  f(10, env)
}

g()
```

Comment: hmm ... but I would have thought that object i would then be looked up in the enclosing environments. Your solution works but is no different from writing env$i, and this would require rewriting each access to each of the previously global objects by prefixing it with env$. I hoped there'd be a trick ...